# Retrieving username from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sidebar, rank

ANSWERED QUESTION:

> So I've made a login and signup feature to my website, but now I would
>   like to add the username's and ranks to the sidebar.. But I can't
>   figure out how to do this, and this is why I am asking you for help.
>   Signup.inc.php:
>
> ```
> <?php
> session_start();
>
> include '../dbh.php';
>
> $fname = $_POST['fname'];
> $lname = $_POST['lname'];
> $uid = $_POST['uid'];
> $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
>
> if (empty($fname)) {
>     header("Location: ../parts/signup.php?error=empty");
>     exit();
> }
> if (empty($lname)) {
>     header("Location: ../parts/signup.php?error=empty");
>     exit();
> }
> if (empty($uid)) {
>     header("Location: ../parts/signup.php?error=empty");
>     exit();
> }
> if (empty($pwd)) {
>     header("Location: ../parts/signup.php?error=empty");
>     exit();
> } else {
> $sql = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uid='$uid'";
> $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
> $uidcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
> if ($uidcheck > 0) {
>     header("Location: ../parts/signup.php?error=username");
>     exit();
> } else {
>     $enpwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
>     $sql = "UPDATE users (fname, lname, uid, pwd) 
>     VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$uid', '$enpwd')";
>
>     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
>     header("Location: ../index.php");}
> }
> ```
>
> ----- Login.inc.php :
>
> ```
> <?php
> session_start();
> include '../dbh.php';
>
> $uid = $_POST['uid'];
> $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
>
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid'";
> $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
> $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
> $hash_pwd = $row['pwd'];
> $hash = password_verify($pwd, $hash_pwd);
>
> if ($hash == 0 ) {
>     header("Location: ../index.php?error=empty");
> } else {
>     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$hash_pwd'";
>     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
>
>     if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
>         echo "Your username or password is incorrect!";
>     } else {
>         $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
>     }
>     header("Location: ../pages/dashboard.php");
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> --------- Sidebar:
>
> ```
>     <?php
>     session_start();
>     if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){ //if login in session is not set
>         header("Location: ../index.php");
>     }
>     include '../include/idtouser.sinc.php';
>     ?>
>     <!DOCTYPE html>
>     <html>
>     <head>
>         <meta charset="utf-8">
>         <title>LoginSystem</title>
>         <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css" type="text/css">
>     </head>
>     <body>
>     <header id="closeNav">
>         <nav>
>               <div onclick="toggleNav()" id="star"><span class="hamburgerico">☰</span></div>
>               <div class="profilePicture"></div>
>               <div id="username">Username</div>
>               <div id="rank"><p>Rank</p></div>
>
>             <ul>
>               <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
>               <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
>               <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
>               <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
>               <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
>               <li><a href="../include/logout.inc.php">Log Out</a></li>
>             </ul>
>         </nav>
> </header>
> ```
>
> ---
>
> What would be the correct way for me to do this?

UNANSWERED QUESTION:
AND -- Is there a way I could translate my ranks (1,2,3,4,5) to actual rank names before posting them in the sidebar?

Comment: a home made signup script in 2016 doesn't sound right.

Comment: your script is vulnerable to sql injections

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I know, I haven't fixed that yet, I am aware of it though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Login Page, add this:

```
$_SESSION['uid']        =   $row[1];
```

Suppose row[1] includes the user id or username

Then in the sidebar:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>
```

I dont know what the rank is for but you can echo out the rank in a similar way as username

Comment: Hey, not sure why but this didn't work for me (?) I edited $row[1] to 2 as that is what my UID is, but it still doesn't work (?)

Comment: Could I ask one more question, if ranks are "1->5" how can I translate this to an actual rank before posting it in sidebar? :D

Comment: Hello, @fizzi I was just wondering if you could answer the question above aswell :D

Comment: if you're using phpmyadmin then add another field called rank having values 1,2,3,4,5 as type enum. suppose it is stored as row[4]. Then in the same way in login page 
$_SESSION['rank']        =   $row[4];
Then in sidebar:
<?php echo $_SESSION['rank']; ?>